# Truncate local table only when Remote table is accessible or have complete data in oracle

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I've a problem which I'm hard to find solution. Hope you guys in this community can solve.

On daily basis I'm copying table from one database(T_TAGS_REMOTE) to table on another database (T_TAGS_LOCAL) through DB links. For this I truncate T_TAGS_LOCAL table first and then perform insert.
Above task is done through Linux job.

Problem comes when

1. Sometimes T_TAGS_REMOTE from remote database is not accessible giving ORA error
2. Sometimes T_TAGS_REMOTE have not complete data rows (i,e SYSDATE COUNT < SYSDATE-1 COUNT)

Requirements:
STOP truncating STOP inserting when any of the above problem (1) or (2) has encountered

MyCode:

```
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) AS OLD_RECORDS_COUNT FROM T_TAGS_LOCAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE T_TAGS_LOCAL';
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO T_TAGS_LOCAL SELECT * FROM AK.T_TAGS_REMOTE@NETCOOL;

END;
/
```

Please suggest BETTER option for table copy or code to handle this problem.

Comment: If you think that `count(1)` is magically faster than `count(*)` you might be interested in [this](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/count-4/) or [this](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/count/)

Comment: Are you copying every day the whole table from source ??

Comment: yes, we are copying whole table on daily basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the technique you are using, it would always generate issues. Instead, I think your use case fits a replication using materialized views. A materialized view log in source, and a materialized view using the dblink in target

You only need to decide the refresh method, that could be FAST ON COMMIT, as I guess your table is not very big as you are copying the whole table each and every single day.

Example

In Source

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number primary key, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL>  declare
 begin
 for i in 1 .. 100000
 loop
 insert into t values ( i , dbms_random.value ) ;
 end loop;
 commit ;
 end;
 /  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create materialized view log on t with primary key ;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> select count(*) from t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    100000
```

In Target

```
SQL> create materialized view my_copy_of_t build immediate refresh fast on demand as 
     select * from your_source@your_db_link

-- To refresh in target

SQL> select count(*) from my_copy_of_t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    100000
```

Now, we change source

```
SQL> insert into t values ( 100001 , dbms_random.value );

1 row inserted

SQL> commit ;

Commit completed.
```

In target, for refreshing

```
SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh('MY_COPY_OF_T');
```

The only requirement for FAST REFRESH ON DEMAND is that  you must have a materialized view log for each of the tables that are part of the Materialized View. In your case, as you are replicating a table, you only need a materialized view log on the source table.

Comment: Hello Roberto, Unfortunately we don't have rights to CREATE materialized view log or any procedure. We have just READ ONLY Access to Source Database. Please suggest any other option.

Comment: @AAMIRKHAN, if you have some requirements but you can't do anything about it, well then you have a problem in the place you are working. I mean, we are talking about some quite standard elements in Oracle designed for replication purposes. If you are not allowed to create anything , perhaps you should be asking yourself what the hell should I do when I can't do anything. If you want to solve your problem, convince your boss to do the right thing

Comment: Also no PRIMARY KEY or any constraints on these tables

Comment: there is an option in materialized view log with rowid

Comment: yeah exactly @Roberto.

Comment: can we apply TRIGGER for restricting table TRUNCATE if condition not fulfilled. Is this option feasible for my requirement. Yeah daily replication with this method is not GOOD one but keeping this on another side.

Comment: everything is possible, normally, but I would never ever implement a DDL trigger to avoid truncate for this. It is a very bad design and probably will create more problems. You will need to control when the truncate is done in order to assure that out of your window the truncate is possible. Please, can you upvote the answer at least for the help you are receiving!

Comment: @AAMIRKHAN, I think you forgot to upvote the answer ;)

Comment: @Reberto I had upvoted many times but still showing 0 but don't why.

Answer (score 0):

A better option might be using a **materialized view**. The way you do it now, you'd refresh it *on demand* using a database job scheduled via `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.